# Loop through table, check name, and add total

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I must be stupid today. I have a table with the same data which includes (among other things) company names and integer values. I need to pick one row, check for each time that name appears in the database, and add the integer value from that row to a total.

ex.

```
 28469151 6398   80609     40032 CITY TREASURER
 25404033 6289   041409CR 39926 CITY TREASURER
 2408266  8473    071009    40017  CITY TREASURER
 22332527 9710   2009     39975 THE ST JOE COMPANY
 21570825 6857   051209CR 39954 CITY TREASURER
```

the program would add the number from row 2 every time it saw "city treasurer". any ideas? There are about 4000 records

Edit: I need to get the total for each company in the table.

Comment: I think you mean column not row. At the moment the question is a little confusing

Comment: Sorry, you are right! I need to say column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that something like this (supposing that the first col is named col1)

```
select sum(col1) from table group by company;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(`field1name`) FROM `table` GROUP BY `field2name`
```

Comment: That would work great, but I need the total for every company in the database. There are about 4000 records.

Comment: Use the answer above that I voted for - effectively you want to group by company